# PT2314 Audio IC AT89C2051

Tags: microcontroller, audio, c, i2c, 8051

How can I interface Audio IC PT2314 with 8051 series micrcontroller (AT89C2051). The audio IC requires SCL SDA (I2C Interface) to control. But in datasheet of AT89C2051, there is no hardware I2C pins.

How can I interface this? I am coding in C.
Any example code and circuit would be of great help.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "bit banging".

Comment: Atmel does not use the I2C term but TWI, two wire interface. Check for that.

Comment: AFAICT, there is neither I2C nor TWI on the AT89C2051. So @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is correct, you will need a 'bit banging' implementation of I2C (or TWI) in C. You'll find several examples using a web search. I tried searching for 'bit banging I2C C 8051' and found several.

Comment: I got it now. I have found some resources and same application code for bit banging.